# write pandas query using pandas-ai

Tags: pandas, pandas-ai, pandasai

Using **[pandas-ai](https://pandas-ai.com/)**, is it possible to ask it to write the pandas query? I'm not interested in running the prompt, I'm interested in seeing the panda query it writes.

For example, if I ask it - `select the last two columns of data`, it should output `df.iloc[:,-2:]`

Comment: If you click 'view code,' it shows you the query it writes.